# Powerpoint 2013 VBA Convert linked charts to embedded

Tags: vba, powerpoint

The case is for powerpoint 2013, where i have got a presentation with around 50 slides, each slide contains a linked chart from an excel sheet, however all the links are there but without the files, in other words the links are broken.

Ofcourse what is required is to make some slight edits to EVERY chart, that would be easy if they are embedded charts - which is not the case. I always try to educate colleges to clean the sheet from all but the pivot workbook of which they are pasting the chart and then paste as an embedded chart - But again this is not the usual case.

I do have a VBA code to copy the data from the broken charts (all the series) to the clipboard which i then use to manually create an excel file with single workbook and manually paste the data (i get them as a single long column with an empty cell separation between every originally-was row), then re-arrange it in the right order then change the source of the chart to point to the new file then edit the data, then copy the chart then paste it identically in its place as an embedded chart after deleting the original one.! :) yes i know ... !

The process is a long tedious no-brains effort which i believe that it can be automated somehow. however my searches did not yield me to any direct powerpoint 2013 capabilities of converting a broken link chart to an embedded one (at least with the data visible - and no need ofcourse to the source workbooks of these data!).

I have found other powerpoint (and non-powerpoint) VBAs that write to excel sheet, copy to clipboard, break chart links, paste charts ... etc., but I have not been in coding VBA for long time now and used to do only for access, so ...

I would really appreciate any help that can be offered in this direction. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025377/vba-powerpoint-updating-embedded-excel-objects     This might help you get started.